# Taking 3 Divs inside one div

Tags: html, css

I have given with design structure as below:

[image]

I am not allowed to use `<table>` for this purpose.

I have used div and inside that div 3 divs for each section 1 , 2 and 3 in image.

**I have tried design code as below:**

```
<div style="right: 0px; position: absolute; height: 77%; width: 40%;" class="sloInputBox">
        <b>Correlations</b>
        <img alt="fullscreen" src="~/Images/fullscreen.png" style="vertical-align: top; padding-right: 55%; float: right" />
        <div id="gvCorrelationData" style="vertical-align: top; height: 60%; top: 3px" class="sloInputBox">
        </div>

        <b>Manual Correlation</b>

        <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 33%; bottom: 2px;" class="sloInputBox">

            <div style="float:left;width:30%;">
                <b>1.</b>
                Select a section of the observation to Correlate.
                <button onclick="ShowSelection();return false;" style="background-color: #249FDA; color: white; height: 22px; width: 45px; border-radius: 4px;">Select</button>
            </div>

            <div style="margin:auto;width:30%;"> 
                <b>2.</b>
                <div class="sloInputBox" style="width: auto; height: 27%">
                  @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList().Name("ddlCode").OptionLabel("Select Code...")
                                                    .DataTextField("codeTitle")
                                                    .DataValueField("compCode").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%;" }))
                </div>
                Select a code to associate with.
                <button onclick="ResetSelectionAndManualCodeddl();return false;" style="background-color: #249FDA; color: white; height: 22px; width: 45px; border-radius: 4px; float: right">Reset</button>
            </div>

            <div style="float:right;width:30%;vertical-align:top;">
                <b>3.</b>
                Save this correlation.
                <button onclick="ManualCorrelation();return false;" style="background-color: #249FDA; color: white; height: 22px; width: 55px; border-radius: 4px;">Correlate</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

But unfortunatele section 3 in this code is not getting in line properly.

Its viewing as below:

[image]

I also tried to set different margines...but it does not helped me.

How can i resolve this issue??

Comment: Definitely looks to be margin- or padding-related. What box-sizing method have you applied? Are you using percentage widths? Paste your HTML and CSS please :)

Comment: If it jumps in line when you reduce widths then you can start from there. Check margins, paddings, width sizes.

Comment: @CyberDude I have tried width upto 20% for first two divs inside...but third div is not comming inline

Comment: @StephenOrr I have not written sepate css for this...my html code is pasted above

Comment: can you make fiddle? i think the issues with a width

Comment: What I started with was removing the `margin:auto;` and set all 3 columns to `float:left` and it begins to work slightly... : http://jsfiddle.net/Wq2np/

Comment: http://jsbin.com/jibexevu/1/edit like this?

Comment: @KheemaPandey yes like this

Comment: @CyberDude your float:left thing worked!!! thank you :)\

Comment: OK, I'll add as answer so you can mark it

Answer (score 2):

**HTML**

```
<div class="n-m1" class="sloInputBox">
    <b>Correlations</b>
    <img alt="fullscreen" src="~/Images/fullscreen.png" />
    <div id="gvCorrelationData"  class="sloInputBox"></div>

    <b>Manual Correlation</b>
    <div class="sloInputBox">

        <div class="n-c1">
            <b>1.</b>
            Select a section of the observation to Correlate.
            <button onclick="ShowSelection();return false;">Select</button>
        </div>

        <div class="n-c1"> 
            <b>2.</b>
            <div class="sloInputBox" >
              @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList().Name("ddlCode").OptionLabel("Select Code...")
                                            .DataTextField("codeTitle")
                                            .DataValueField("compCode").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%;" }))
            </div>
            Select a code to associate with.
            <button onclick="ResetSelectionAndManualCodeddl();return false;">Reset</button>
        </div>

        <div class="n-c1">
            <b>3.</b>
            Save this correlation.
            <button onclick="ManualCorrelation();return false;">Correlate</button>
        </div>

    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.n-m1  b {
    display:block;
}

.n-c1 {
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    height:150px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    margin-left: 10px;
}   

.n-c1:first-child {
    margin-left:0;
 }

.n-c1 > button {
    background-color: #249FDA; 
    color: white; 
    height: 22px; 
    width: 100px; 
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}



.n-m1 > img {
    padding-right: 55%; 
    float: right
}

.n-m1 > img + div {
    height: 60%; 
    top: 3px;
}
```

**<kbd>[Code example](http://jsfiddle.net/Xk857/4/)</kbd>**

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do remove `float` from the child `div` and use `display:table` on parent div and `display:table-cell` on child div.

check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/jibexevu/1/edit)**.

Answer (score 1):

I started by removing the `margin:auto;` and set all 3 columns to `float:left` and it begins to work slightly... : [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Wq2np)

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a working demo.[**Refer here**](http://jsfiddle.net/shadowstrike/fu4JJ/)

```
<body>
<div style="/* right: 0px; */ /* position: relative; */ /* height: 77%; */ width: auto;border: 2px dashed #f0f0f0;" class="sloInputBox"> <b>Correlations</b>
<img alt="fullscreen" src="~/Images/fullscreen.png" style="vertical-align: top; padding-right: 55%; float: right">
<div id="gvCorrelationData" style="vertical-align: top; height: 60%; top: 3px" class="sloInputBox"></div> <b>Manual Correlation</b>

</div>
<div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 33%; bottom: 2px;width: 100%;margin-top: 19px;" class="sloInputBox">
<div style="float:left;width: 33.3%;height: 105px;"> <b>1.</b>
Select a section of the observation to Correlate.
        <br>
    <button onclick="ShowSelection();return false;" style="background-color: #249FDA; color: white; height: 22px; width: 45px; border-radius: 4px;">Select</button>
    </div>
    <div style="margin:auto;width: 33.3%;float: left;"> <b style="float: left;">2.</b>

        <div class="sloInputBox" style="/* width: auto; */ /* height: 27% */">
            <select style="width: 50px;">Select box
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        Select a code to associate with.
        <button onclick="ResetSelectionAndManualCodeddl();return false;" style="background-color: #249FDA; color: white; height: 22px; width: 45px; border-radius: 4px; float: right">Reset</button>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left;width: 33.3%;vertical-align:top;"> <b>3.</b>Save this correlation.
        <button onclick="ManualCorrelation();return false;" style="background-color: #249FDA; color: white; height: 22px; width: 65px; border-radius: 4px;">Correlate</button>
    </div>
</div>
```